# Django dynamic ModelChoiceField field

Tags: python, django

Trying to pass in a variable to help with the queryset that `ModelChoiceField` requires. Getting error `TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)` and I'm not sure why. See code below.

forms.py

```
class uploadForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, trainer, *args, **kwargs):
        super(uploadForm, self).__init__(trainer, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["client"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                      queryset=Trainee.objects.filter(trainer=trainer),
                      widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'signup-form-input'})
                   )
```

views.py

```
uploadForm = uploadForm(trainer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this exception because following code line is wrong:

```
super(uploadForm, self).__init__(trainer, *args, **kwargs)
```

In init method. It should be just

```
super(uploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

as in super class's constructor `trainer`  is not an argument.

Anyways, the way you are doing is wrong! you should implement your form class as below:

forms.py:

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["client"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Trainee.objects.filter(trainer=kwargs['trainer']),
            widget=forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'signup-form-input'
                }
            ))
```

views.py:

```
uploadform = UploadForm(trainer=trainer)
```

One more note: If `trainer` is not a field in your form then popup `trainer` before to call super class constructor as:

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        trainer = kwargs.pop('trainer', None)  
        super(UploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["client"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Trainee.objects.filter(trainer=trainer),
            widget=forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'signup-form-input'
                }
            ))
```

views.py is as I given in my answer.

Comment: You've outdone yourself sir. Super helpful. Thanks a bunch, works perfectly. Sorry for the poor presentation as well. It was 1am my time and being dead tired makes a person a little lazy lol

Comment: @AustinBailey your welcome mate :) , -- one more tip make habit to use class name start with upper case.

Comment: I'm so used to camelcase from JavaScript. I guess it's carried over to python lol

Comment: @AustinBailey yes, I believe in JavaScript also class name starts with upper case (I may be wrong but as I remember in Java class name starts with uppercase e.g. String). Yes other variables starts with lowercase in camelcase style.